# how do I autofill a date field with the date of 'today'

Tags: alan

In Alan, how do I annotate a date field so that it is autofilled with the current date upon entry creation.
for example:

```
'Creation Date': natural 'date'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application.alan annotate the number property as follows:

`'Date': integer 'date' @default: today`

FYI, for date-and-time properties you can use the `now` default.

More info: https://alan-platform.com/pages/docs/model/30/application/grammar.html